# Problem to generate the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, hyphenation

Compiling a large document which worked properly some two months ago, now causes an error. The document was not changed, but I'm updated my MikTeX on a regular basis. Because of the complexity of the project I have no idea how to reduce the document a minimum working example and/or to start the search for the error.

The error is described in the log-file as

[251] [252]) (_Typo-A4.aux
! Argument of \cb@pdfparsexy has an extra }.

\par
l.696 ...y{1}{226}{21095303}{35318221}{36.96628pt}
^^M

WinEdt highlights in the aux-file the line

\cb@pdfxy{1}{226}{21095303}{35318221}{36.96628pt}

in

\citation{Tschichold1975}
\cb@pdfxy{1}{226}{21095303}{35318221}{36.96628pt}
\cb@pdfxy{2}{226}{21095303}{35318221}{460.10347pt}
\cb@barpoint{1}{227}{4.0pt}
\cb@pdfxy{3}{226}{7645188}{31677740}{36.96628pt}
\cb@pdfxy{4}{226}{7645188}{31677740}{460.10347pt}
\cb@barpoint{4}{227}{4.0pt}
@writefile{brf}{\backcite{Tschichold1975}{{92}{24}{Hfootnote.109}}}

The bib-entry is
@Book{Tschichold1975,
author    = {Tschichold, Jan},
publisher = {Birkhäuser},
title     = {\textbf{Ausgewählte Aufsätze über Fragen der Gestalt des Buches und derTypographie}},
year      = {1987},
address   = {Basel},
edition   = {2. Auflage},
}

I found some hints on latest germen hyphenation problems but changing the language settings to

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\babelprovide[hyphenrules=ngerman-x-latest]{ngerman}
did not help.

Where can I start to identify the problem?

Comment: I doubt that the citation is the problem, the error happens when rereading the aux-file. If you quit at the error, does the aux have content that you can show?

Comment: Does it really help to show up the whole aux-file with 1796 lines?

Comment: I got it: It is the section between \cbstart and \cbend in an \item. Whenever I delete that sections it works fine.

Comment: well less lines would be easier, but as you don't know which lines are important ...

Comment: Now knowing that it is an issue with changebar I will check this in a minimum working example. Then I will see whether this is a problem with the latest version of that package. If not … it will be a nice testing which one of the many packages in my typography project causes that problem whenever I use changebar.
Thank you, Ulrike, for your answers.